# Flask - Why i see robots.txt in server answer?

Tags: python, flask

I have simple Flask web aplication running on my localhost (started with command "flask run").

This web app works with more languages, that are detected from URL.
For example: 'http://localhost:5000/en/article'

On index page must be URL: 'http://localhost:5000/en/', but if use this code:

```
@blueprint.route('/<string:lang_code>/')
def home(lang_code):
    print('Show lang:', lang_code)
```

output is:

```
Show lang: robots.txt
```

and no lang code from URL.
Why i see this output? Which is best practice for using/detecting language code in URL?
Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

When your server is facing public (or even during testing locally), you have to expect arbitrary requests. The obvious response to requests, which do not obey your URL schema, is a `404 Not Found`. This means you should check if `lang_code` is one of the languages you support.

The [`/robots.txt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file is used to limit the access for search engines. However, there is no guarantee that search engines obey these restrictions.

The method you are using is a common technique to support multiple languages. Other common techniques involve URL parameters, e.g., `?lang=en`, or cookies. Please note, that browser also indicate the users language preferences via the HTTP header field `Accept-Language`. This could be used to redirect to the version of the page in the preferred language if any other language indications are missing.

Comment: thank you for yours answer, but still cannt understand why i dont see lang code, but string "robots.txt". In my opinion, my solution is based on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/urlprocessors/ and would be see land code if use URL http://localhost:5000/en/article

Comment: If you request `http://localhost:5000/en/`, you should see `Show lang: en`. However, apparently there are also requests like `http://localhost:5000/robots.txt`. Python/Flask puts the string `robots.txt` into `lang_code` and prints it. It doesn't know that `lang_code` should be a language, nor does it know that `robots.txt` is not a language.